# Horizontal Thumbnail Scroller with Lightbox Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, thumbnails, lightbox, scroller

I need a free thumbnail scroller with left and right arrow but after clicking on a thumbnail it should open like the lightbox jquery.

Here's an example : 
http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-image-content-scroller-w-lightbox/full_screen_preview/112734

Please suggest.i have been searching all over the internet but not able to find anything like the above

Help Very Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Jquery Malsup](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) it has a lot good configurable options